# Why is data formatted changed after converting to ts from csv?

Tags: r

```
date
DCOILBRENTEU
1   5232    1284
2   5255    1269
3   5278    1277
4   5350    1282
5   5374    1284
6   5397    1282
7   5420    1282
8   5443    1280
9   5675    1286
10  5934    1288
11  6194    1293
12  6240    1296
13  6263    1286
14  6335    1293
15  6359    1296
16  5699    1296
17  5722    1288
18  5745    1296
19  5817    1
20  5841    1307
21  5864    1320
22  5887    1322
23  5910    1322
24  6005    1326
25  6029    1307
26  6052    1293
27  6075    1289
28  6098    1324
29  6170    1329
30  6217    1324
31  6382    1315
32  6642    1336
33  6900    1343
34  7019    1357
35  7043    1359
36  7066    1357
37  7089    1372
38  6405    1376
39  6477    1383
40  6501    1387
41  6524    1415
42  6547    1424
43  6570    1438
44  6665    1432
45  6689    1420
46  6712    1419
47  6735    1407
48  6758    1365
49  6830    1341
50  6854    1380
51  6877    1396
52  6924    1409
53  6947    1400
54  7631    1463
55  7703    1439
56  7726    1381
57  7749    1378
58  7772    1370
59  7136    1352
60  7160    1354
61  7183    1359
62  7206    1349
63  7229    1336
```

Data changed in the above format after converting csv to ts. I have two problem:

1. is to visualize these data as they are very compacted?
2. how can I change this data in normal format?

[image]

Comment: So much unknown information...Please: 1. Show your R command to (a) import the csv file, (b) convert the R object into a "ts", and (c) produce that graph. And 2.  please show a sample of the data using `dput` or other method. Thanks a bunch. 

Comment: Hi Jan. Welcome to StackOverflow! If you want to improve your question, here is some information on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [minimale reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). The MRE will make it easier for others to find and test a answer to your question. That way you can help others to help you!